# Coordinates of cylinder's other side after a rotation?

Tags: 3dsmax, maxscript

I'm creating an object and rotating it, but I need to know the location of the other side of this cone object after rotation. Can anyone help?

```
newCone = Cone heightsegs:1 capsegs:1 sides:12 height:10 radius1:0.5 radius2:0.5 pos:[0,0,0]
rotate newCone (angleaxis 60 [0,0,0])
```

Answer (score 1):

Unless the cone will be scaled at some point, it's enough to add the height in the direction the cone is pointing to its position:

```
Point pos:(newCone.pos + newCone.dir * newCone.height)
```

Note also that the `[0,0,0]` in your code will be normalized to `[0,0,1]` which is probably not what you are after – as it is now, it's actually the same as `angleAxis 60 -x_axis`.